# Unable to load one or more of the requested types in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

**Disclaimer**: I have seen the exact questions, but have not seen any answers that could solve my problem.
**Server**: Windows Server 2008 with ASP.NET 4.0 Framework (Client Profile and Extended) installed.
**Scenario**: This does not happen at my development server, it only happens on my production server and so my debug capabilities are very limited.
Problem: When I click on a page which loads data using EntityDataSource I my elmah gives me this.

> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException
>   Unable to load one or more of the
>   requested types. Retrieve the
>   LoaderExceptions property for more
>   information.

No very helpful Stack Trace too. So I used the event `Application_Error` inside `Global.asax` like this  to get more details on the error like this.

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Exception objErr = default(Exception);
    objErr = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

    Server.ClearError();
    if (objErr is ReflectionTypeLoadException) {
        ReflectionTypeLoadException reflerror = default(ReflectionTypeLoadException);
        reflerror = (ReflectionTypeLoadException)objErr;
        foreach (var ex in reflerror.LoaderExceptions) {
            sb.AppendLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    sb.AppendLine("<b>Source:</b>" + Request.RawUrl);
    sb.AppendLine("<br><b>Browser:</b>" + Request.UserAgent);
    sb.AppendLine("<br><b>IP:</b>" + Request.UserHostAddress.ToString());
    sb.AppendLine("<br><b>UserID:</b>" + User.Identity.Name);
    sb.AppendLine("<hr><br><b>Error in: </b>" + Request.Url.ToString());
    sb.AppendLine("<br><b>Error Message: </b>" + objErr.Message.ToString());
    sb.AppendLine("<br><b>Stack Trace: </b><br>" + objErr.StackTrace.ToString());
    Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new Exception(sb.ToString()));

}
```

Now I get the error logged as,

> System.Exception
>   Could not load file
>   or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc,
>   Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.
>   **Source:**/consultant/search
>   
> **Browser:**Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 6.1; rv:5.0)
>   Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0
>   
> **IP:**my ip
>   
> **UserID:**user1020
>
> ---
>
> **Error in:**
>   http://mysite.com/search
>   
> **Error Message:** Unable to
>   load one or more of the requested
>   types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions
>   property for more information.
>   
> **Stack Trace:** 
>  at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule
>   module) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
>   at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
>   at
>   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemConventionAssemblyLoader.LoadTypesFromAssembly()
>   at
>   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAssemblyLoader.Load()
>   at
>   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly
>   assembly, Boolean
>   loadReferencedAssemblies,
>   ObjectItemLoadingSessionData
>   loadingData) at
>   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly
>   assembly, Boolean
>   loadReferencedAssemblies,
>   KnownAssembliesSet knownAssemblies,
>   EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection,
>   Action`1 logLoadMessage, Object&
>   loaderCookie, Dictionary`2&
>   typesInLoading, List`1& errors) at.... (the trace goes on)

Please look at the first line.

What is `System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0` doing in an ASP.NET Scenario?
I have asked my server guys to install MVC3. But this really does not make any sense.
Any help / pointers will be much appreciated. I have not been this baffled in a long time with asp.net :(

Why this error happens and what will be a good solution / workaround?

Comment: Did you check web.config? It might be there some references to this dll

Comment: @adrian: absolutely no adrian. :) sorry for the delayed reply. i slept off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had issues with 3rd party references needing MVC to work, DotNetOpenAuth comes to mind.

Comment: Adding the reference to MVC3 solved the issue. Still dont know why.